# Best way to add a space when joining values

Tags: php

What would be the best way to implement spaces in my variable so that I can display it like `value | value` and not `value|value`

**Code:**

`$pageTitle         = $pageName . '|' . $siteName;`

Comment: Just: `'|'` -> `' | '`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is your solution:**

```
$pageTitle         = $pageName . ' | ' . $siteName;
```

**Anyway you can use this to:**

```
$pageTitle         = $pageName . '&nbsp;|&nbsp;' . $siteName;
```

**In this last, you can give 1,2,3 or more spaces, example:**

$pageTitle         = $pageName . '   |   ' . $siteName;

```
$pageTitle         = $pageName . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $siteName;
```

**Reference:** http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.